# Avoid excessive use of IllegalStateException

Tags: java, oop

I'm  currently having the following class

```
public class ContentContainer {
    private enum ContentState {
        NEW,
        IN_UPLOAD,
        UPLOAD_FINISHED,
        IN_TRANSFER,
        TRANSFER_FINISHED
    }
    
    // Persisted in Postgres DB
    private UUID uuid;
    private ContentState state;
    private List<ContentPart> parts;
    private Integer expectedParts;
    
    public void addContentPart(ContentPart contentPart) {
        if (this.state != ContentState.IN_UPLOAD) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        parts.add(contentPart);
        
        if (this.parts.size() == this.expectedParts) {
            this.state = ContentState.UPLOAD_FINISHED;
        }
        // persist in db
    }
    
    public void transfer() {
        if (this.state != ContentState.UPLOAD_FINISHED) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        // transfer
    }
}
```

There can be e.g. 20 HTTP requests adding Content. Now if someone triggers the `/transfer` endpoint before all 20 parts are added, there should be an exemption.

Is there a better available design pattern to avoid the ContentState comparsion in every request to `transfer`?

Comment: Key word here is state - use a simple 2 step state machine .. transition when applicable .. only one method does anything in each state. Currently you have 2 responsibilities in one class, adding and transfer .. break that up into single responsibilities. You could go even further inside each "state" interface implementation map a state to a command using Command Pattern, so state machine decides what it does, command then executes the action .. Just couple ideas off top my head ..

Comment: @MarkKeen Would a state machine even make it easier? I still have to check the state in the endpoint. If you emit the event TRANSFER, but the state isn’t completed, you’d need to have a user facing error. So in the end still checking and setting the state in every endpoint

Comment: If you let it get this far without defensive checks you already throw an unchecked exception so I don't really understand your point about having to tell the user when you can't validate or complete their request? If a user doesn't fill in a form correctly is an app supposed to crash or tell them what's not yet valid? As to your original question, you have added behaviour based on an enum.. as some point, wherever you abstract it, you have to define the behaviour.  My comment suggests design patterns backed up with rationale .. adding your use cases kind of moves the goal posts without context

Comment: @MarkKeen Exceptions can have context and be mapped to JSON representations of the error. The examle can easily swap out exceptions, while the state machines can usually only report the transition not existing. When I have to look up source and target and find out what I can show the user it's kind of like what I have already isn't it? Not sure what is moving the goal posts there

Comment: "Exceptions can have context and be mapped to JSON representations of the error." -not sure how JSON gets involved specifically. It should really be using checked exceptions if you're not using defensive checks .. wrapping unchecked exceptions in try/catches seems like a code smell .. as to your original question without architecture rethink you can't remove checking of state as you have delegates to your container class rather than just telling it what to do. Currently data and logic are coupled .. but that's not necessarily bad as it's encapsulated. I'd advocate one class one responsibility

Comment: So in my case: user performs /transfer, state isn't upload_finished, throws TransferNotPossibleException(currentState). Spring ControllerAdvice maps TransferNotPossibleException to JSON error, user sees {"code": "xyz", "message": "abc"}. I'm just not sure how I'd even do that with state machines, since e.g. spring state machine offers `sendEvent` and returns false if there's no such transition defined.

Comment: Maybe consider returning a `Result` for each method either `Success()` or `Failure(String reason)` - check for the happy path in each method, ultimately returning Success if not then Failure, then let the client handle? However it seems any upset to this classes API might upset clients that currently use it?